# Close all other UL's on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written this code below for a mobile navigation. Everything works well, but when opening a UL i want the other UL's to close. Does anyone know how to write this?

fiddle code:- http://jsfiddle.net/t7gucozm/4/

```
$('nav > ul li a').on('click', function (ev) {
    if ($(this).next('ul').length > 0) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {

        } else {
            $(this).addClass('opened');
            $(this).next('ul').show();
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: What is the level of parent child hierarchy ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$('nav > ul li a').on('click', function (ev) {
    if ($(this).next('ul').length > 0) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
            $(".opened").removeClass('opened');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('opened');
            $(this).next('ul').show();
            ev.preventDefault();
        } 
    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: This doesnt work - all the parent ul's are still opened.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('nav > ul li a').on('click', function (ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).next('ul').length > 0) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
            $(".opened").removeClass('opened');
            $(this).next('ul').hide()
        } else {
            console.log($('li'))
            $('li a').each(function () {
                 $(this).removeClass('opened')
                 $(this).next('ul').hide()
            });


            $(this).addClass('opened');
            $(this).next('ul').show();

        } 
    } 
});
```

Comment: This doesnt work - all the parent ul's are still opened.

Answer (score 0):

I already handled a similar situation with css alone

Do let me know if u want a strict Jquery solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/arunzo/t7gucozm/5/

```
ul li ul {
    display:none;
}

nav>ul>li>a:focus+ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            $('nav > ul li a').on('click', function (ev) {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('opened')) 
                    $('nav .opened').removeClass('opened').next().hide();

                if ($(this).next('ul').length > 0) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {

                    } else {
                        $(this).addClass('opened');
                        $(this).next('ul').show();
                        ev.preventDefault();
                    } 
                } else {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one .

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7gucozm/26/) .

I have added **class="li-lable"** to each parent **li a**

like this one

```
<li>
      <a class="li-lable" href="#">child4</a>
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#">child41</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">child42</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">child43</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
</li>
```

JS -

```
$('nav ul li a ').on('click', function (ev) {
if ($(this).next('ul').length > 0) {

    $(this).parent().siblings().children().not(".li-lable").fadeOut()

     $(this).next('ul').find('li ul').hide()
     $(this).next('ul').fadeIn()

} else {
    alert('no submenu, redirect');
}
```

});